# Does Cloud Run support server sent events (SSE)?

Tags: google-cloud-run

We can't get SSE to send from containers on Google Cloud Run. I've tried hosting a container with just a simple SSE example (https://github.com/kljensen/node-sse-example) to see if it was something in our library -- nope.

I see from the server that clients connect (like the initial GET works), but no events get sent from the server. The `EventSource` on the client never changes from `CONNECTING` to `CONNECTED`.

From the Cloud Run docs, it's a little ambiguous if this would be supported (emphasis mine):

> Cloud Run (fully managed) currently does not support HTTP streaming. Therefore, inbound requests with protocols like WebSockets and gRPC (streaming RPCs) are not supported.
>
> As an exception, Cloud Run (fully managed) services support unary gRPC for inbound requests.
>
> For **outbound requests**, both WebSockets and gRPC are supported on Cloud Run (fully managed).

Wouldn't SSE count as outbound requests, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: See my updated response and consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE (October 8, 2020):** Server streaming is now supported https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-http-grpc-server-streaming

<strike>Not currently. However, this feature (gRPC server-side-streaming and SSE) will be launched very soon. We're working on it actively, stay tuned.</strike>

Comment: So you mean once the feature is delivered, we will be able to keep connections for free, and only pay when data is sent from server to client ?

Comment: Unlikely. As long as the HTTP request is open, that will be charged.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google this is awesome to hear! We are pumped to have this feature. Just curious - does this also mean the maximum request timeout will increase from 900 seconds?

Comment: @AhmetB-Google any update on SSE support, or is there somewhere we can look to keep up to speed on this going forward?

Comment: SSE is coming soon. Make sure to follow GCP Blog Serverless section.

Comment: This is now supported https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-http-grpc-server-streaming

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan server sent events still seem to be buffered for me? i deployed an express server with an sse endpoint to cloud run, and when i call it, it just takes 10 seconds and then delivers me the full response, instead of streaming the data to my client (works perfecltly when not using cloud run). anything i am missing?

Comment: Same as @Patric here. I'm trying to configure Remix response streaming on Firebase Functions v2 and it seems the responses are always buffered and them sent as a whole instead of actually streamed.

Comment: @gustavopch I found out the problem for me is actually firebase hosting, not cloud run. I use firebase to redirect all calls to /api to my cloud run instance. and by doing this, the sse traffic also goes through firebase hosting, and there it is buffered. when i directly use my cloud run container url, it all works fine. however, this kind of sucks, because in my region it's not possible to have custom container urls, so the url looks very random, and i would prefer to be able to just call mydomain.com/api, or api.mydomain.com....

Answer (score 1):

If I refer to the Cloud Run design, the container processing is performed only when a request is handled, the rest of the time, the CPU is close to idle. That's why you are billed only when a request is processed.

If I take the SSE flow, the server initiate a connection to the client. You need processing time (and resources) for establishing and maintaining this connexion. And because it's out of any request, your CPU is idle and it can't work for performing this.

So, I don't have a clear answer to your implementation problem, but, by design, I'm quite sure that Cloud Run can't work with SSE. At least, for now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, by outbound requests, they mean the requests made by your container on Cloud Run to some other service.
As mentioned by Guillaume, it's currently not possible to stream responses and I guess it's also related to the fact that Cloud Run will buffer every response.

I am myself looking for a workaround and will keep you posted if I find any decent solution

Answer (score 1):

Well, the current temporary workaround is switching to Google App Engine **Flexible** and disable response buffering with `X-Accel-Buffering: no` response header.